# Javascript sorting array by partial string

Tags: javascript, sorting, matching

I have an array like this

```
 var myArray = [ 
    "J20J205147902_B_B716202",
    "R20Q205147902_F_B716202",
    "P20W205147_902_alternate1",
    "M20K205147_902_alternate4",
    "F20G205147_902_alternate3",
    "K20J205147_902_alternate2",
    "L20H205147_902_main"];
```

I want to sort this array by this pattern

```
var map = { 
    "_F_":1,
    "_main":2,
    "_alternate1":3,
    "_alternate2":4,
    "_alternate3":5,
    "_alternate4":6,
    "_alternate5":7,
    "_B_":8
};
```

So, the output should be like this

> "R20Q205147902_F_B716202",
>   "L20H205147_902_main",
>   "P20W205147_902_alternate1",
>   "K20J205147_902_alternate2",
>   "F20G205147_902_alternate3",
>   "M20K205147_902_alternate4",
>   "J20J205147902_B_B716202"

Comment: Please clearly define your question; you don't seem to have actually asked anything. Additionally, you should include an attempt or snippet that works towards your desired output. Right now this 'question' sounds more like you're just requesting someone write code for you, which is **not** what we're here for.

Comment: You can find a solution using `Object.keys()`, `Array#map`, `Array#sort`, `Array#filter` and `String#indexOf`. Good luck!

Comment: Look at some of the example functions here to get an idea and use Chris G's suggestions to build a compare function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use a custom sorting comparator function as follows:

```js
var myArray = [
  "J20J205147902_B_B716202",
  "R20Q205147902_F_B716202",
  "P20W205147_902_alternate1",
  "M20K205147_902_alternate4",
  "F20G205147_902_alternate3",
  "K20J205147_902_alternate2",
  "L20H205147_902_main"];

var map = {
  "_F_":1,
  "_main":2,
  "_alternate1":3,
  "_alternate2":4,
  "_alternate3":5,
  "_alternate4":6,
  "_alternate5":7,
  "_B_":8
}

myArray.sort((...args) => {
  const [a, b] = args.map(str => Object.keys(map).find(key => str.includes(key)))
  return map[a] - map[b];
})
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Hey antonku. As an effort to keep StackOverflow free of bad questions, it's generally frowned upon to answer them; you've more-or-less just convinced OP that we're a code-writing service. Though obviously your intentions were to help (and that sentiment is genuinely appreciated), providing solutions for these ends up doing more harm than good. For more information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194989/400248